# Run the Server in the background

Tags: python

I have installed superset in python virtual env on GCP VM. I am running the superset using following command inside the virutal env.

`gunicorn -w 5 --timeout 120 -b 0.0.0.0:8088 "superset.app:create_app()"`

But when i  terminate my SSH connection the server stops, How to run SupserSet forever irrespective of my SSH connection.

Comment: consider using systemd, crond, screen, supervisord or something else

Comment: This is not specific to SuperSet or Python, not even really to SSH. It's also not a programming question, hence off-topic here. Consider superuser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can usually run commands as a daemon using:
`nohup <your command> &`